# Word for "that which shows the reality behind a phenomenon"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a tool, or concept, that allows you to see the reality behind a certain physical phenomenon, or a tool that exposes the behind-the-scenes details? For example, *backstage* would be one of such words.

A totally made up word is perfectly fine!

Comment: Note that *phenomena* is the (Greek) plural of *phenomenon*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to be creative, such a tool might be called an "endoscope".

Since such a tool elucidates, one could coin "elucigen" as something that generates elucidation.

Answer (score 4):

You could say that those tools are [revelatory](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/revelatory):

> making people aware of something that they did not know before
>   *a revelatory insight*

A related word is [*enlightening*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enlightening).

Comment: Sounds very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside some arcane philosophical considerations, a **scientific explanation** is precisely the tool that allows us to see what is behind the natural pheonomena.

Comment: sorry doesn't fit the context

Comment: What is the context, exactly?

Comment: the context isn't science or research. it's something more metaphysical or playful.

Answer (score 1):

The tool, if there is one, is used to unmask. Maybe you could call it *The Unmask tool* or, shorter still, *The Unmasker*.

Comment: Very interesting, this is the sort of stuff I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The term **debunk** works, though it is typically used when the truth behind a phenomenon contradicts the supernatural/over-the-top explanation previously given.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some ideas reading the introduction from David Hilbert's article stating some 23 challenging problems in mathematics. He says:

> Who of us would not be glad to lift the veil behind which the future
>   lies hidden; to cast a glance at the next advances of our science and
>   at the secrets of its development during future centuries?.

So you can speak of a tool/method/theory that helps us *lift the veil* behind behind which the truth about physical phenomena lies hidden. Equivalently you may use the verb unveil or unravel. You can talk about *God's blueprint when we determined the laws of nature* and so on and so forth (You can improvise).

Answer (score 0):

Your question reminds me of the *man behind the curtain* from the Wizard of Oz. So if your context is silly (as you mentioned in a comment), you could use terms like ***curtain-lifter***, ***curtain-smasher***, etc.

You might also refer to 'going backstage' as:

- lifting the veil
- seeing nuts and bolts / gears / guts

Using those phrases, you can make up words like ***deveiler*** or ***deconstructor***.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the stuff I'm looking for. Now I wish I could check multiple accepted answers.